How to plot two raster results in the same graph with the legend of non-numeric variables？
I plot two graphs with the code below:
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

plot_simulation <- function(input_file) {
  Results <- read.csv(file = input_file, sep = ",", dec = ".", header = TRUE)
  Results$CLocation <- gsub(" ", "", Results$wlieu)  # 去除列 wlieu 的空格字符
  medianYield <- aggregate(mafruit ~ CLocation, data = Results, FUN = median)
  
  SimulatedPoints <- read.csv(file = "./LinPoints.csv", sep = ",", dec = ".", header = TRUE)
  SimulatedPoints$CLocation <- gsub("^(\\d{2})_(\\d{1,2})$", "\\1_0\\2_v3test", SimulatedPoints$CLocation)
  SimulatedPoints$CLocation <- gsub("^(\\d{2})_(\\d{3})$", "\\1_\\2_v3test", SimulatedPoints$CLocation)
  
  SimulatedPointsCoords <- SimulatedPoints[, c("Grid_Code", "CLocation", "latitude", "longitude")]
  SimulatedPointsCoords$CLocation <- gsub(" ", "", SimulatedPointsCoords$CLocation)
  
  Results <- merge(SimulatedPointsCoords, medianYield, by = "CLocation", all = TRUE)
  
  sf_Results <- st_as_sf(x = Results, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
  
  cell_size <- 30000

  utm_crs <- st_crs(st_transform(sf_Results, 32631))
  sf_Results_projected <- st_transform(sf_Results, utm_crs)
  
  bounds <- st_bbox(sf_Results_projected)
  x_min <- bounds["xmin"] - cell_size / 2
  x_max <- bounds["xmax"] + cell_size / 2
  y_min <- bounds["ymin"] - cell_size / 2
  y_max <- bounds["ymax"] + cell_size / 2
  
  raster_template <- raster(
    xmn = x_min, xmx = x_max, ymn = y_min, ymx = y_max,
    res = cell_size, crs = utm_crs$wkt
  )
  
  raster_Results <- rasterize(
    x = st_coordinates(sf_Results_projected),
    y = raster_template,
    field = sf_Results$mafruit,
    fun = median
  )
  
  url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson/master/regions.geojson"
  france <- st_read(url)
  france <- st_transform(france, crs = utm_crs)  # 转换为 UTM 坐标系
  
  raster_Results_wgs84 <- projectRaster(raster_Results, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
  france_wgs84 <- st_transform(france, crs = 4326)
  
  color_breaks <- c(0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0)
  #colors <- c("#E31A1C", "#FF7F00", "#FDBF6F", "#E9E4A6", "#A4D4A9", "#B2DF8A", "#33A02C", "#1F78B4")
  colors <- c("#9B1A1A","#E31A1C", "#FF7F00", "#FDBF6F", "#B2DF8A", "#33A02C", "#1F78B4","#084E6A")
  
  p <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = france_wgs84, fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = 0.7) +  
    geom_tile(
      data = as.data.frame(raster_Results_wgs84, xy = TRUE),
      aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)
    ) + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(
      colors = colors,
      breaks = color_breaks,
      labels = as.character(color_breaks),
      name = expression("Yield (t·ha"^-1*")"),
      na.value = NA,
      limits = c(min(color_breaks), max(color_breaks))
    ) +
    coord_sf(
      xlim = c(st_bbox(france_wgs84)$xmin, st_bbox(france_wgs84)$xmax),
      ylim = c(st_bbox(france_wgs84)$ymin, st_bbox(france_wgs84)$ymax),
      expand = FALSE
    ) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
      legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
      legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
      legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"),
      legend.spacing.y = unit(0.5, "cm"),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white")
    ) +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(
      title = expression("Yield\n(t·ha"^-1*")"),  
      barwidth = 0.5, 
      barheight = 10, 
      title.position = "top",
      title.hjust = 0.5,
      label.position = "right",
      direction = "vertical",
      frame.colour = "black"
    ))
  

  return(p)
}

files <- c(
  "MGI_Pallador_irri_0.65_late_sowing.csv",   
  "MGI_Pallador_no_irri_0.65_late_sowing.csv"
)

plots <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  plots[[i]] <- plot_simulation(files[i])
}

grid.arrange(grobs = plots, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

And I want the graph below:

But I want to combine these two figures into one figure:
Step 1.Combine the values in the same cell and choose the highest one.
Step 2.Assign two colors to these two files, and replace the highest value selected in Step 1 with the color corresponding to the file it came from. Additionally, create a legend using these two files.
Here is the expected result image:
""
IMPORTANT: The result map also needs to be raster type!
Original data:
LinPoints <- read.csv("LinPoints.csv")
dput(LinPoints)
structure(list(Grid_Code = c(31351652L, 31331654L, 31331655L, 
31331657L, 31331658L, 31291905L, 31261906L, 31121911L), CLocation = c("73_63", 
"73_63", "73_63", "73_63", "73_63", "73_73", "73_73", "73_73"
), elevation = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 20L, 20L), latitude = c(43.3697, 
43.3909, 43.3926, 43.3961, 43.3978, 43.8155, 43.8436, 43.9751
), longitude = c(-4.4804, -4.4606, -4.4484, -4.4241, -4.412, 
-1.4018, -1.3949, -1.3582)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

MGI_Pallador_irri <- read.csv("MGI_Pallador_irri_0.65_late_sowing.csv")
dput(MGI_Pallador_irri)
structure(list(wlieu = c("                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test"), mafruit = c(1.367, 
1.626, 1.661, 1.558, 1.145, 1.772, 1.86, 1.776, 2.748, 2.832, 
2.705, 2.994, 0.689, 0.846, 1.158, 0.656, 0.699, 0.846, 1.158, 
0.656, 2.532, 2.677, 2.569, 2.994, 2.554, 2.775, 2.591, 2.94, 
2.468, 2.835, 2.665, 2.818)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
> 

MGI_Pallador_no_irri <- read.csv("MGI_Pallador_no_irri_0.65_late_sowing.csv")
dput(MGI_Pallador_no_irri)
structure(list(wlieu = c("                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_063_v3test", 
"                           73_063_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test", "                           73_073_v3test", 
"                           73_073_v3test"), mafruit = c(1.098, 
1.235, 1.582, 0.981, 1.145, 1.772, 1.86, 1.776, 1.664, 1.981, 
2.193, 2.674, 0.689, 0.846, 1.158, 0.656, 0.699, 0.846, 1.158, 
0.656, 2.068, 2.144, 1.97, 2.994, 1.599, 1.693, 1.216, 2.3, 2.108, 
2.734, 2.294, 2.726)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))


For two "terra" rasters with identical grid bases, doing gt = r1 > r2 will tell you where r1 is greater than r2, and then its just a case of plotting that with appropriate colouring and labelling. Do you have to use ggplot for this? Its tedious to use when it can't handle rasters as-is. Try tmap...

Oh I tried tmap many times. It failed.

When I do this with your data I get that one raster - the one with "irri" is bigger than the other ("non-irri") in all non-NA locations, so your final map would only have one colour in it. The raster for "irri" is a 2x2 block of 2.671 and one cell of 1.4625, whereas "non irri" has a corresponding 2x2 block of 2.126 and a cell of 1.158. Is that right, or have I messed up putting your data back into a CSV and reading it back again? (also why do you read France from a WGS84 source, convert to a UTM zone, then back to WGS84?)

First lets break this down into some functions, the first one takes an input file path and returns a raster:
get_simulation <- function(input_file) {
  Results <- read.csv(file = input_file, sep = ",", dec = ".", header = TRUE)
  Results$CLocation <- gsub(" ", "", Results$wlieu)  # 去除列 wlieu 的空格字符
  medianYield <- aggregate(mafruit ~ CLocation, data = Results, FUN = median)

[...plus more lines from your source up to...]

  raster_Results_wgs84 <- projectRaster(raster_Results, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

  return(raster_Results_wgs84)
}

Then get France with:
get_france = function( ){
  url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson/master/regions.geojson"
  france <- st_read(url)
  return(france) # this is in wgs84
}
france = get_france()

Now read the files and get the rasters:
r_irri = get_simulation(files[1])
r_nonirri = get_simulation(files[2])

As supplied, one raster is bigger than the other everywhere, so for testing lets tweak one cell:
r_nonirri[5,1] = 2

Now convert the difference to a data frame, remove NAs, and create a factor column which is what we're going to use in ggplot:
diffs = as.data.frame(r_irri > r_nonirri, na.rm=TRUE, xy=TRUE)
diffs$Status = factor(c("Irrigated","Non Irrigated")[diffs$layer+1])

Then this ggplot get the fundamentals:
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=france) +
    geom_tile(data=diffs, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=Status))


Garnish that with whatever other ggplot herbs and spices you need.
Not sure what trouble you are having with tmap, but a basic example is:
tm_shape(france) + tm_polygons() + 
   tm_shape(r1>r2) + tm_raster(labels=c("Non-Irri","Irri"))


which can be styled and coloured to taste. But maybe further tmap problems warrant a new question (and maybe on http://gis.stackexchange.com)

Some example data
library(terra)
r1 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=runif(100), ext=c(0,1,0,1))
r2 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=runif(100), ext=c(0,1,0,1))

Which layer has the highest value?
x <- which.max(c(r1, r2))

You can now make a plot like this:
plot(x, plg=list(legend=c("Irrigated", "Rainfed")))

Or like this
levels(x) <- data.frame(id=1:2, value=c("Irrigated", "Rainfed"))
plot(x)


Or with ggplot:
tidyterra::autoplot(x)

# or 

ggplot2::ggplot() + tidyterra::geom_spatraster(data=x)


